# iPhoto AlbumData.xml OriginalPath vs ImagePath

Tags: photos.app, plist

In the `AlbumData.xml` for some images in the `Master Image List` exists `OriginalPath` and `ImagePath` like:

```
<key>94734</key>
<dict>  
        ... some lines deleted ...
        <key>ImagePath</key>
        <string>/Volumes/tssd/Users/jm/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Previews/2014/11/01/20141101-134854/EJw9YL%KSnG7rLMxx5KEOA/P1020607.jpg</string>
        ... some lines deleted ...
        <key>OriginalPath</key>
        <string>/Volumes/tssd/Users/jm/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters/2014/11/01/20141101-134854/P1020607.JPG</string>
        <key>ThumbPath</key>
        <string>/Volumes/tssd/Users/jm/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Thumbnails/2014/11/01/20141101-134854/EJw9YL%KSnG7rLMxx5KEOA/P102060
7.jpg</string>
        ... some lines deleted ...
</dict>
```

For some images, the `OriginalPath` entry is missing and exists only the `ImagePath`, like:

```
<key>ImagePath</key>
<string>/Volumes/tssd/Users/jm/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters/2014/11/01/20141101-134854/P1020610.JPG</string>
```

Can somebody explain

- what is the difference between `OriginalPath` and `ImagePath`
- why some images has both entry and why some only the `ImagePath`?

Comment: Because i'm not an very active user of this site, I doesn't care much about the reputation changes - but would be nice to know, what is wrong this this question - e.g. would be nice to know the reason of the down vote - and how i could improve the question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out,

- if the `OriginalPath` entry doesn't exists, the `ImagePath` contains the path to the imported image.
- if the `OriginalPath` entry exists, it points to the imported (original) image, and the `ImagePath` points to the modified image (e.g. rotated, or enhanced and such).